# Oracle 10g default username and password

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to import a database dump file into Oracle 10g.  I'm very very new to Oracle.

I've installed  Oracle Server ok, but when I go to SQLPlus, I'm prompted for a username and password. I've entered the defaults I found on websites (sys/sys, sys/change_on_install
system/manager, scott/tiger) but none are being accepted.

Comment: system/manager should work, but you need to specify `as sysdba` when you login.

Comment: Hi, 10x I got somewhere at least... now it's telling me "insufficient privileges"

Answer (score 3):

When you built your database, you should have been prompted for a password at some point for the system and sys accounts. That's the password you need to use.

The comment above about logging in with "as sysdba" with the user SYSTEM is incorrect. SYSTEM does not have SYSDBA privilege.

If you've forgotten or don't know the password(s) you specified for these accounts, you can sneak in through the back door by doing the following (assuming Windows):

1. Add your Windows user ID to the ORA_DBA group.
2. In a command window, set ORACLE_SID appropriately and enter "sqlplus / as sysdba"
3. You should be logged in as SYSDBA. You can now reset the passwords as @Gaius stated.
4. One other potential gotcha is that you may need to modify the sqlnet.ora file in your ORACLE_HOME/network/admin folder to contain the line SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(NTS) if you continue to get the "insufficient privileges" error in step 2.

Answer (score 2):

Do this at the Unix shell prompt as the Oracle user:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

You should get a prompt back saying SQL>. Now say

```
SQL> alter user whoever identified by whatever;
```

Then you can log in as

```
$ sqlplus whoever/whatever
```